# Redis (PHP-Redis) SCAN and KEYS show different results with same pattern

Tags: redis, glob, phpredis

I am using PHP-Redis with Redis Version 3.1.6

```
$result = $redis->keys('source_1234_[a-zA-Z]*_[0-9]*');
```

produces

```
{array} [6]
 0 = "source_1234_test_1"
 1 = "source_1234_test_2"
 2 = "source_1234_test_3"
 3 = "source_1234_test_4"
 4 = "source_1234_test_5"
 5 = "source_1234_test_6"
```

However

```
$iterator = 0;
$result = $redis->scan($iterator, 'source_1234_[a-zA-Z]*_[0-9]*');
```

returns

```
FALSE
```

I am reading the docs for [KEYS](https://redis.io/commands/keys) and [SCAN](https://redis.io/commands/scan) but all it says it that supports glob-style patterns.

So checking http://www.globtester.com/ I can confirm that the pattern is valid and should return the correct results. Why is there a difference and why does SCAN return FALSE in this case?

Comment: check the output of those commands using redis-cli, it's probably related to the phpredis.

Answer (score 3):

Two problems with your code:

(a) You need to set the iterator to `NULL`, not `0`.

`0` is returned from the call to `SCAN` to indicate that all keys have been scanned. It will therefore stop and return `false`.

(b) `SCAN` iterates over sets of all keys, returning the matches from each set for each call. You're only calling scan once. It will scan the first `COUNT` keys and return false if none of those happen to match.

See https://redis.io/commands/scan#number-of-elements-returned-at-every-scan-call:

> SCAN family functions do not guarantee that the number of elements returned per call are in a given range. The commands are also allowed to return zero elements, and the client should not consider the iteration complete as long as the returned cursor is not zero.[...]

To get identical results to `KEYS` you need to iterate over all sets of keys:

```
$iterator = NULL
while($iterator != 0) {
    $arr_keys = $redis->scan($iterator, 'source_1234_[a-zA-Z]*_[0-9]*')
    foreach($arr_keys as $str_key) {
        echo $str_key;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, when I use the code the `$arr_keys` is returning an empty array, so never goes into the `foreach`.

Comment: I've changed it slightly, try again. Haven't done PHP in 14 years :)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like that:

```
$redisClient = new Redis();
$redisClient->connect($config['devices']['redis_ip']);
$redisClient->setOption(Redis::OPT_SCAN, Redis::SCAN_RETRY);
$start_time = microtime(TRUE);
$it = NULL;
while ($keys = $redisClient->scan($it, "useragent:*")) {
    foreach ($keys as $key){
        // Do something with the key
        usleep(1000);
    }
}
$end_time = microtime(TRUE);
$time = $end_time - $start_time;
echo "\t[done]: Total time: {$time} seconds\n";
$redisClient->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I was looking for this, I'm posting what worked for me

```
$iterator = null;
while(false !== ($keys = $redis->scan($iterator, $pattern))) {
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        echo $key . PHP_EOL;
      }
 }
```

I took this from the documentation of `scan` of `php-redis`.
This should print every key matching the `$pattern`.

Comment: This won't change the iterator and will cause an infinite loop, and the returned value from scan command is an array of 2 elements, the 1st is the next cursor and the 2nd is the `keys`, in case if no keys found and the cursor is 0, it will return false.